# the import javax.jms cannot be resolved

Tags: eclipse

He copiado un codigo desde internet a eclipse.
pero tengo problemas con los imports.
no he podido dar con la solucion.
muchos import marcados como error con el mensaje "The import ... cannot be resolved".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puede que [esta respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13825794/3791844) te sea te ayuda.

Comment: Simplemente no tienes el archivo jar incluido al proyecto. (javax.jms)